# Wait for process to exit using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

I had a little program in F# (similar to C#), that gets processes by name, then filters the particular one by its path and waits for it to exit:

```
let processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("MyProcessName")
if (processes.Length > 0) 
    then for proc in processes do
            if (proc.MainModule.FileName = "C:\Example\MyProcessName.exe")
                then proc.WaitForExit()
```

But this code works only on local computer. Now I want to achieve the same functionality on remote computer.

So that's why I choose PowerShell (I'm completely new to it).

**Is it possible to filter process by it's path and wait for it to exit using one line in powershell?** If not, maybe you can provide longer solution?

How I will execute this line on remote computer I already have an idea. All I need is just that magical line.

EDIT: Actually this line should work on local machine, because I'm going to pass it using msdeploy, which executes it on remote machine as a local command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spent some time playing with powershell and finally got what I wanted:

```
powershell.exe ps | ? { $_.path -eq 'c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe' } | Foreach-object { $_.WaitForExit() }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would invoke a `Wait-Process` on the target machine. See this post for detailed code:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18341767/powershell-check-on-remote-process-if-done-continue

Comment: Just edited my first post. This command should work on local machine, because I'm going to pass it to remote machine using msdeploy, which executes this line as a local command.